# Can anybody help me read this XML file and tell me what I am looking at

Tags: python, xml, cc

I need to be able to read what is on each row and column, for example what is on row D3, but am unsure how I can do this. I know it makes a spreadsheet but what is the code or language this is written in and how can I learn to read specific info from this source?

I am under the impression it's xml and has the completed table that it creates but am still unable to make clear how I read what is on each row or column.

```
<wf:table h="85" w="405" range="A1:D5">
<wf:fmts>
<wf:bdrFmts>
<wf:bdrFmt style="solid"/>
<wf:bdrFmt style="double"/>
</wf:bdrFmts>
<wf:fillFmts>
<wf:fillFmt color="#0094ff"/>
</wf:fillFmts>
<wf:valFmts>
<wf:valFmt fmtStr="MMMM D, &lt;new_line> YYYY" typ="dateTime"/>
<wf:valFmt typ="text"/>
<wf:valFmt outScl="6" typ="accounting" thouSep="true"/>
</wf:valFmts>
<wf:txtFmts>
<wf:txtFmt fontFamily="Arial"/>
<wf:txtFmt fontWeight="bold" textAlign="center" fontFamily="Arial"/>
<wf:txtFmt fontWeight="bold" fontFamily="Arial" color="#00cc00"/>
</wf:txtFmts>
<wf:condFmts/>
</wf:fmts>
<wf:cols>
<wf:col w="201" />
<wf:col gutter="3.35" w="100" />
<wf:col w="4" />
<wf:col gutter="3.35" w="100" />
</wf:cols>
<wf:rows>
<wf:row h="25">
<wf:c tFmt="1"/>
<wf:c formattedString="June 30, &#xA;2016" tFmt="2" val="6/30/2016" vFmt="1" bFmt="0|.     0|0|1"/>
<wf:c tFmt="1"/>
<wf:c formattedString="December 31, &#xA;2015" tFmt="2" val="12/31/2015" vFmt="1" bFmt="0|0|0|1"/>
</wf:row>
<wf:row h="15">
<wf:c formattedString="Debt Securities" tFmt="1" vFmt="2" val="Debt Securities"/>
<wf:c formattedString="1,000" tFmt="1" fFmt="1" val="1000" inScl="6" vFmt="3"/>
<wf:c tFmt="1"/>
<wf:c formattedString="1,200" tFmt="1" fFmt="1" val="1200" inScl="6" vFmt="3"/>
</wf:row>
<wf:row h="15">
<wf:c formattedString="Equities" tFmt="1" vFmt="2" val="Equities"/>
<wf:c formattedString="500" tFmt="1" val="500" inScl="6" vFmt="3"/>
<wf:c tFmt="1" />
<wf:c formattedString="600" tFmt="1" val="600" inScl="6" vFmt="3"/>
</wf:row>
<wf:row h="15">
<wf:c formattedString="Money Market Funds" tFmt="1" vFmt="2" val="Money Market    Funds"/>
<wf:c formattedString="200" tFmt="1" fFmt="1" val="200" inScl="6" vFmt="3"/>
<wf:c tFmt="1"/>
<wf:c formattedString="200" tFmt="1" fFmt="1" val="200" inScl="6" vFmt="3"/>
</wf:row>
<wf:row h="15">
<wf:c formattedString="Total Cash Equivalents" tFmt="1" vFmt="2" val="Total Cash Equivalents"/>
 C
 <wf:c tFmt="1" />
 <wf:c formattedString="2,000" tFmt="3" formula="SUM(D2:D4)" val="2000" inScl="6" vFmt="3" bFmt="0|0|1|2"/>
</wf:row>
</wf:rows>
</wf:table>
</wf:Worksheet>
</WFML>
```

Comment: Did you search for the opening tag name or the namespace attached?

Comment: The url now redirects to a different website, but we can assume this is accounting software, judging by the new location.

Comment: I also see connections to SEC filings, so presumably this is a markup language to submit your SEC filing via the web. It'll be a [SGML document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language).

Comment: I know it who it belongs to the company is now Workeva,as part of a test I was asked to tell them what figure is in d3 and what the total was on the 30th of june. but it is not clear to me how i should have known this information from this data and am trying to figure out if somebody else understood and could explain. sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: I also find references to http://www.wfmc.org/, but their standards page makes no mention of this. It appears to be an entirely obsolete format, gone from the web. The very few references found call it a *XML derived markup language*, which still sounds a lot like SGML.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I guess I will have to do what I can and keep on scratching my head.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) module in Python can easily traverse though any sort of XML-looking code like this.

After putting your code inside of a string I've named `pagecode`, I ran this to extract what was in the fourth row, third column:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(pagecode, 'lxml')
rows = soup.find_all("wf:row")
cell = rows[3].find_all("wf:c")[2]  # Indexing starts at 0, not 1!
print(cell)  # Displays <wf:c tfmt="1"></wf:c>
```

Comment: No, don't treat this as HTML, it is not HTML. Just because the parser manages to accept this, doesn't mean there won't be errors in the parsed result.

Comment: Note that it is not BeautifulSoup that does the parsing here, it is the lxml HTML parser that does the actual work. BeautifulSoup then gives you an API to manipulate the parsed objects.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look into this in more detail tomorrow.

Comment: Martijn, even if "lxml" is what's under the hood doing the actual parsing, the example I gave still works with the code given.  What would you use instead?